# How does Ramda.map over Immutable.List return a List instead of an Array?

Tags: javascript, iterator, immutable.js, ramda.js

I have created a List of Maps in Immutable.js which looks like:

```
List [ 
  Map { "id": 0, "name": "John" }, 
  Map { "id": 1, "name": "Lennon" } 
]
```

Now, I have used Ramda's R.map to map over the above list:

```
R.map(map => map.get('id'))(a)
```

It returns a new List of id's which is of type `Immutable.List`, but not a JS `Array`.

```
List [ 0, 1 ]
```

I understand that we can iterate over any data structure if it's `Symbol.iterator` is defined. But the returned type is also a `List`.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a `List` is explained in the [Ramda documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map):

> #### `map`
>
> Dispatches to the `map` method of the second argument, if present.

The second argument in your case is a `List`. And yes, a `List` has a `map` method, as found in the [Immutable documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/map):

> #### `map`
>
> Returns a new `List` with values passed through a mapper function.

So that explains why you get a `List`.